# rewrite rule check for string existence

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need a `RewriteRule` which changes an url of `http://domain.org/foo/bar` to `http://domain.org/de/foo/bar` but does nothing if there is an url like `http://domain.org/en/foo/bar` or `http://domain.org/de/foo/bar`

so if there is no `en/` and no `de/` then it should add `de/`, else it should do nothing

how can this be done? i already played around a bit with regex, but I dont know how to check if there is `en/` or if there is no `en/`.

help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
my current rules are the default rules you should have when running wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**UPDATE2:**

this is wordpress and de/ and en/ are not actual folders.. they are used by a multilanguage plugin. since i have some issues with this plugin i need the redirect as described above.

Comment: Can you put your current rules in the question? We need to see code so there is no conflict with any suggestion made.

Comment: i added my current rules now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:en|de)).*)$ de/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Keep this rule before default WP rule.

---

**EDIT** Full .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:en|de)).*)$ de/$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: hm i get internal server error. same when trying the other rule from below. why? see: http://i.imgur.com/exPJWqj.png
htaccess looks like this: http://pastebin.com/01dLCKWM

Comment: when trying your updated solution i get: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: i changed the line `RewriteRule ^((?!(?:en|de)/).*)$ de/$1 [L,NC,R]
` to `RewriteRule ^((?!(?:en|de)).*)$ de/$1 [L,NC,R]` to avoid some issues while switching languages. but besides that, the solution worked!

Comment: one more thing: do you mind explaining what the rule is actually doing step-by-step? :) would be really appreciated.

Comment: i'd especially be interested in why it's doing nothing when it detect en/ ?

Comment: `(?!(?:en|de)` is a negative lookahead regex that fails the match if URI starts with `en` or `de`.

Answer (score 2):

In general without any other rules, this would redirect anything that doesn't start with `/en/foo/bar`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: okay. how can i make it agnostic of  the `foo/bar` part? i mean i want to redirect anything that doesn't start with `/en/`

Comment: thanks. but i get internal server error whyn i try to use your code: http://i.imgur.com/exPJWqj.png

Comment: hm error log says: `[Wed May 13 17:13:15 2015] [error] [client 128.131.168.136] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: The first part of the my rule works fine. But you also have it out of order in your .htaccess rules you pasted. Did you try it exactly as I have it shown there?

Comment: Wait so `de` is not a real directory correct? and you have wordpress in the root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77730/discussion-between-beta-and-panama-jack).